Issue when enabling TLS in Fluent-bit with Elasticsearch as output
I am setting a EFK stack in a Kubernetes single host cluster. Everything works perfectly with http. However, when I enable TLS in Fluent-bit ConfigMap, I experience the following error:
[2024/07/04 16:51:57] [error] [tls] error: unexpected EOF
[2024/07/04 16:51:57] [ warn] [engine] failed to flush chunk '1-1720111186.704158600.flb', retry in 84 seconds: task_id=47, input=tail.0 > output=es.0 (out_id=0)
[2024/07/04 16:51:58] [error] [tls] error: unexpected EOF
[2024/07/04 16:51:58] [error] [tls] error: unexpected EOF
[2024/07/04 16:51:58] [ warn] [engine] failed to flush chunk '1-1720111346.704169721.flb', retry in 612 seconds: task_id=208, input=tail.0 > output=es.0 (out_id=0)
[2024/07/04 16:51:58] [ warn] [engine] failed to flush chunk '1-1720111588.707272575.flb', retry in 68 seconds: task_id=450, input=tail.0 > output=es.0 (out_id=0)

Note that TLS works perfectly between Kibana and Elasticsearch, so their configuration seems to be fine.
Now, I have the following config for Fluent-bit for the output plugin:
output-elasticsearch.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name              es
        Match             *
        Host              ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}
        Port              ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}
        Logstash_Format   Off
        Replace_Dots      On
        Retry_Limit       False
        Suppress_Type_Name On
        tls             On
        tls.verify      Off
        tls.debug       3
        tls.ca_file     /fluent-bit/tls/tls.crt
        tls.crt_file    /fluent-bit/tls/tls.crt
        tls.key_file    /fluent-bit/tls/tls.key    
        HTTP_User       ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER}
        HTTP_Passwd     ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}

This, in order to mount the certificates, in my daemonSet.yaml:
spec:
  containers:
    - name: fluent-bit
      image: fluent/fluent-bit:3.0.7 # Latest
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      ports:
        - containerPort: 2020
      env:
        - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
          value: "elasticsearch"
        - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
          value: "9200"
        - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER # Una vez funcione, cargar con secreto
          value: "kibana_system" # I am taking advantage of kibana's user
        - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
          value: "herethepassword"
      volumeMounts:
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
        - name: fluent-bit-config
          mountPath: /fluent-bit/etc/
        - name: tls-certs
          mountPath: /fluent-bit/tls
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
  volumes:
    - name: varlog
      hostPath:
        path: /var/log
    - name: varlibdockercontainers
      hostPath:
        path: /var/lib/docker/containers
    - name: fluent-bit-config
      configMap:
        name: fluent-bit-config
    - name: tls-certs
      secret:
        secretName: elasticsearch-certs

The elasticsearch-certs is the same that I am currently using with elasticsearch, which is working for the Kibana-elastic communication.
I have found someone with the same issue, not really sure if it is a bug or something is missconfigured: https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/8452
Also, as said, Kibana works, but is doing the request via URL, not really sure if this means something:
spec:
  containers:
    - name: kibana
      image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.14.1 # Ojo. Same, exactly version than elastic search!!
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: 1000m
          memory: 1Gi
        requests:
          cpu: 700m
          memory: 1Gi
      env:
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_URL
          value: https://elastic-search.basajaun-cluster:30738
          # SERVICE_TOKEN elastic/kibana/kibana-system = AAEAAWVsYXN0aWMva2liYW5hL2tpYmFuYS1zeXN0ZW06VnNGcmF0TlJUY1dGYkRla01OekVvZw
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME
          value: "kibana_system"
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
          value: "thepassword"
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERIFICATIONMODE
          value: "none" # Solo en entornos de desarrollo, para producción usar "full"
      ports:
        - containerPort: 5601

Any help is appreciated.
